# My select Rails helper isn't returning values when adding multiple =>true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I am new to Rails and i try to make a select form helper with multiple selection , include_blank, prompt something and finally with a bootstrap class 'form-control' such as follow:

```
<%= f.select :non_token_word , [['Type A', 'Type A'],
                     ['Type B', 'Type B'],
                     ['Type C', 'Type C'],
                     ['Type D', 'Type D'],
                     ['Type E', 'Type E']
                    ],
                    { prompt: "Select days" },  
                    { :multiple => true, class: "form-control"} %>
```

but `:non_token_word` returns nothing even not found in INSERT_INTO Only when adding multiple => true .
Any help please.

Comment: Does it generate the HTML you expect it to? When you submit the form, does the Rails log show the request and params you expect it to?

Answer (score 0):

Type is also a reserved word.

Try switching to `:letter_type` (your example)  or `type_of` (more generic).

You'd need to update your db or map in your controller to reflect the rename too.

Rails uses type to manage STI (Single Table Inheritance)
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html.

Comment: I changed it to be another name but still as it is. ThanX , But not a correct answer.

Comment: This can actually be circumvented. Specifying a nonexistent column name in `inheritance_column` effectively frees `type` for custom use.

Comment: I edited my question to forget the word ( type ) , I said that the select returns nothing only when adding multiple => true, then , I hope the solution about how to make select syntax with my requirements. thanX again.